# why upload code cant work in browser than firefox 28?

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

This is my uploaded code . It working in my browser but can`t work in other browsers in other systems , and IE :| this code must access user to upload zip files ,

```
            function GetRandomName(){
            settype($randtxt, "string");
            $temp = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            for($i=0; $i<15; $i++){
                $tekrar = rand(0,strlen($temp)-1);
                $randtxt .= $temp[$tekrar];    
            }
            return $randtxt;
        }// end of func GetRandomName
        function GetTypef($name){
            $back = strpos($name,".");
            $front = strlen($name) - $back;
            $type = substr($name,$back,$front);
            return $type;
        }
            if (isset($_POST['days'])){
            $ex = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $ex_format = end($ex);
            if (($_FILES["user-file"]["type"] == "application/zip")
                or($_FILES["user-file"]["type"] == "application/x-zip-compressed")
               or($_FILES["user-file"]["type"] == "application/x-rar-compressed")
               or($_FILES["user-file"]["type"] == "multipart/x-zip")
               or($_FILES["user-file"]["type"] == "multipart/x-rar")
             && ($_FILES["user-file"]["size"] < 1000000)) {

                if ($_FILES["user-file"]["error"] > 0){
                    $_SESSION['msg2']="error";
                    $check_result = 0;
                    }
                else{
                    if (file_exists("../request-file/" . $_FILES["user-file"]["name"])){
                        $rand_name = GetRandomName();   // get ranadom name for pictures
                        $type_file = GetTypef($_FILES["user-file"]["name"]);   // get type of file;
                        $filename = $_FILES["user-file"]["name"] =  $rand_name  . $type_file;  
                        }
                    else{    
                        $rand_name = GetRandomName();   // get ranadom name for pictures
                        $type_file = GetTypef($_FILES["user-file"]["name"]);   // get type of file;
                        $filename = $_FILES["user-file"]["name"] =  $rand_name . $type_file;   //change file names      
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user-file"]["tmp_name"],"../request-file/" . $_FILES["user-file"]["name"]);
                        $q = sprintf("INSERT INTO requestfile ( `uid`, `tarikhersal`, `hour`, `days`, `name`, `file`, `translate`, `subject`, `translateto`, `translatein`) VALUES ( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s', '%s');",$_SESSION["us"],$jalali_date,$jalali_hour,$_POST["days"],$filename,$_FILES["user-file"],$_POST["translate"],$_POST["subject"],$_POST["translateto"],$_POST["translatein"]);
                    mysql_query($q);
                    $_SESSION['msg']="OK ";
                    header("location:follow.php");      
                        }}}
            else{
                if($_FILES["user-file"]["size"] > 1000000){
                    $_SESSION['msg2']="big size";
                }else {
                    $_SESSION['msg2']="again upload";
                }
                  }}
```

What's the problem? and how can fix it ? please help , im very dizzy...

Comment: Php has nothing to do with the browser

Comment: I suspect the MIME type, check what the other browsers send and repost.

Comment: This code is unreadable. Clean it up. If code makes you dizzy the code is bad.

Comment: how can fix this code ? what the problem ?

Comment: @Doge please give me a unreadable code for uploade zip file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your browser has extension which helps to upload this file.

Please check with another files and test it. if you have a problem in file edit index.php file for show errors.

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```